# What is the advantage of determining scopes statically and using them dynamically in case of Python?

Tags: object-oriented, python, scope, python-3.x

Firstly let me clarify that I know C and am learning Python. So my OOPS is kind of bad.

I was reading [the official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) and found this

> Although scopes are determined statically, they are used dynamically. At any time during execution, there are at least three nested scopes whose namespaces are directly accessible:
>
> - the innermost scope, which is searched first, contains the local names
> - the scopes of any enclosing functions, which are searched starting with the nearest enclosing scope, contains non-local, but also non-global names
> - the next-to-last scope contains the current module’s global names
>   the outermost scope (searched last) is the namespace containing built-in names

I understand namespaces. I think scopes are the same thing. But I couldn't figure out what does the sentence about scopes mean? What is the advantage of such an arrangement?

I understand the sentence but couldn't visualize that. So please don't say that this is problem with my English.

Comment: Scopes are rather different than namespaces. C does not have namespaces, but it does have scopes. C only has local and global scope, Python has some more, most importantly the outer function scope (C does not have nested functions, so there can't be any outer function).

Comment: Note, that this has absolutely nothing to do with object oriented. Closures (inner functions keeping access to the outer function variables) are functional programming concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It lets you pass around those functions which use names from the surrounding context in their behaviour.

You see this a lot when defining decorators:

```
def make_bold(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        return '<b>{}</b>'.format(func(*args, **kw))
    return wrapper

@make_bold
def hello(name):
    return 'Hello {}!'.format(name)

hello('World')  # returns '<b>Hello World!</b>'
```

Here the `wrapper` function accesses `func` from the parent function scope; `func` is a local variable in the `make_bold` function. `wrapper` is a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29); `wrapper` *closes over* `func`.

You can expand on this a little more by making the decorator configurable:

```
def format(tag):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            return '<{0}>{1}</{0}>'.format(tag, func(*args, **kw))
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@format('b')
@format('i')
def hello(name):
    return 'Hello {}!'.format(name)

hello('World')  # returns '<b><i>Hello World!</i></b>'
```

Now we have *two* levels of scoping; `tag` comes from the local namespace of `format()`, while `func` is a argument for the `decorator()` function; both are used by `wrapper()`.

Comment: The fancy name for these are "closures"

Comment: What is this `@make_bold`? I have just reached the classes part in tutorials and haven't seem them till now.

Comment: @AseemBansal: It is a decorator. Everything after the `@` must result in a function, and that function is passed the  function below the line, and the return value of the decorator *replaces* that function. Effectively, `@make_bold` added before `def hello(...)` results in `hello = make_bold(hello)` right after `hello` has been evaluated.

Comment: Instead of `It lets you pass functions around that` it might be better to use `It lets you pass around those functions which`. It's confusing because of use `around that` in the sentence as in `Can you go around that corner?`. Still reading your answer and trying to understand closures. I'll reply after spending some time on the wikipedia page.

Comment: @AseemBansal: I can update that, but 'to pass around' *has* that meaning, quite separate from 'around the corner'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, it has that meaning. I am not saying otherwise but here it confused me so I suggested that.